# add apple iAd to app update

Tags: ios, iad

Real quick question here,I have an app that I have already submitted to the app store for approval. Can I had iAd support to my app after submitting it in the app store, i.e. in a future update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. A later update can add or remove any functionality you want, including iAd. The only thing an update can't do is reduce the hardware supported by the update. The primary exception to this rule is you are allowed to update the Deployment Target to a newer version of iOS.

Comment: thanks a lot, now I just need to figure out a way to implement it in UISplitviewController.